# Check GruntJS Verbosity Level

Tags: gruntjs

I have a library that handles its output independently, via an options object. I would like to be able to configure its verbosity level based on whether `--debug` or `--verbose` were passed on the CLI to Grunt. Is there a mechanism exposed to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var verbose = grunt.option('verbose') || grunt.option('debug');
```